# Should a moving average be applied to time series data before performing a linear regression?

Tags: regression, moving-average

[image][image: Canadian Teenage Fertility Rate]

I have a time series that I want to perform a linear regression on.
It occurred to me that first applying a moving average to the data set and then 
the linear regression might help to smooth out the data and provide a better fit.
Often in time series one point will be above trend and then the subsequent point will be below.
Smoothing out data with moving averages makes a great deal of intuitive sense. 
Is such presmoothing a typical procedure followed in linear regression?

When I actually applied this idea to my dataset, the linear regressions were
almost identical. I suspect the main difference would show up in R with 
differences in sums of squares.

My question arises from a sociology assignment related to the book "The Spirit Level". From what I can see the book uses hopelessly flawed statistically analysis. Nevertheless this book has been widely embraced by the public and entered the policy discussion about how we should structure taxes in modern society.

Essentially, the entire book shows figures with linear regressions for the 23 wealthiest nations in the world that relate income inequality to all the social ills of contemporary society. The premise of the book is that people living in wealthy nations now have so much money that wealth no longer has positive marginal utility and it would be so much better if we were to simply  increase income equality. The argument is that almost everyone in society (even those near the top of the income distribution) would benefit. The glaring statistical problem is that the conclusion is highly dependent upon which nations are included in the analysis. If a different set of nations are chosen the correlations between income inequality and social bads drops to ~0.

Something that I have noticed is that when the social bads are examined in a time series there is a strong time trend that appears completely independent of changes in income inequality. For example in the graph above, when I fit a 4th order polynomial to the Canadian teenage fertility time series over the last 60 years R2 = 0.989.

The polynomial fit seems almost too good to be true. Many other of the so called social bads of life likely also have very strong time trends. Given this I am very uncomfortable with the analysis used in the book where the time axis is completely ignored and is replaced with an income inequality axis which has correlations for different social outcomes from ~0.45- ~0.85.

My hunch is that if I were to perform multiple linear regression starting with time and then adding in income inequality etc. that income inequality would not be found to be statistically significant.

Any comments would be appreciated. In particular it would be especially helpful if suggestions for specific statistical analyses might be given.

Comment: Sorry I got locked out of editing my comment after 5 minutes. What I noted was that the teenage fertility rate was presmoothed over 5 year increments. I only noticed this when I differenced the time series and found that each 5 year block had a constant difference. This arises because the statistic is only collected every 5 years; they then smooth it from there. This is somewhat disappointing because the R2 of 0.97 is then inflated. It is not showing the true variation that is present in the series. There is no obvious way that I can think of to give a more honest portrayal of the variation.

Comment: I realize that Stack Overflow likes to run a tight ship, though I have had some very interesting experiences lately as I have developed a better understanding of R and how it can help me with my assignment. Foremost amongst these insights is that Stack Overflow should include a R Markdown embedded tutor bot on the site. When I registered with the R Studio Community they had such a tutor and it was great. It would save a great deal of frustration for everyone if the basics of R could be placed into such a self-tutoring R.rmd file. I am very surprised that this has not been done.

Answer (score 1):

No as you can incorporate lags of the output series and contemporary and lag structure for causal series while detecting the presence of latent deterministic structure. See http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf for a discussion of regression and time series analysis leading to a SARMAX model https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf .

Fitting high order polynomials is never a good idea ( for a ton of reasons !) unless you have some theory to support it as has been numerously documented on this site.

The social sciences especially sociology often leads the way in erroneous methodology when time effects are involved as assumptions are either unknown/unstated or go begging for attention.